# Filter values in linq orderby

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

Is there a way to filter the value -1 (from the `IndexOf` when txt not found in item) in the below query?

```
var sortedArray = array.OrderBy (item => item.IndexOf(txt)).ToArray();
```

Any pointers will be helpful.

If I use Where, it would be using `IndexOf` twice, is there a way to use `IndexOf` only once?

Comment: Would doing `Where` then `OrderBy` be too slow for you?

Comment: Do you mean you want to filter from array the items where item.IndexOf(txt) == -1? In that case you need to use Where first, as @Matthew just indicated

Comment: @Matthew, I did that, but just wanted to know if there is someway I could do it using OrderBy.

Comment: @Sam: You can't leave values out entirely with an `OrderBy`.

Comment: @Sam - You can sort them last, but you can't remove them.  `OrderBy` returns the same thing, just in a different order.

Comment: @Sam you could probably write an extension method to do this, but keep in mind that `OrderBy` and `Where` are for different purposes.

Comment: OrderBy is not a filtering function, it's a sorting function. It operates on every member of a set....nice try though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid having to do the same `IndexOf` twice you can do:

```
var sortedArray = (from a in array
                  let i = a.IndexOf("txt")
                  where i >= 0
                  orderby i
                  select a).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Where` to do your predicate, and then `OrderBy` later on.

```
var sortedArray =
    array.Where   (item => item.IndexOf("txt") != -1)
         .OrderBy (item => item.IndexOf("txt")).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is just to put a `.Where()` clause first.

```
var sortedArray = array.Where (item => item.IndexOf(txt) != -1)
                       .OrderBy (item => item.IndexOf(txt))
                       .ToArray();
```

This will probably cause a notable performance impact on large arrays or large data in the array, though, since you're now searching for it twice.